# How to associate downstream app in heroku pipelines beta?

Tags: heroku

I've set up my first Heroku pipeline and added apps to development and production - but how do I enable the promote button and associate an app with its production counterpart?

I don't see anything in the docs and the promote button doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: have you gone to staging yet?

Comment: I don't have a stage env... and I also don't have a promote button to go to staging either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines

> The Promote button will only be available if there are apps in the
> subsequent stage(s). In other words, if staging has an app to be
> promoted to production but the production stage doesn’t contain any
> apps, there will be nothing in which to promote the staging app, and
> thus no promotion target.